# Accessing a controller's property from an extended object in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js

I'm trying to access and write/edit a property on a separate controller from an extended object. I've tried using `this.get('controllers.photos');` and including the controller without luck. I've also tried `this.controller('photos').get('uploadPhotos')` and a number of obscure implementations. I've included an example of my code below.

I have a controller with a property `uploadedPhotos`

```
App.PhotosController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  uploadedPhotos: [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

I then have an object that handles my uploading and stores the IDs of the images.

```
App.Upload = Ember.Object.extend({
 ...some ajax call
  success: function(file, response){
     App.PhotosController.uploadedPhotos = response;
  }
});
```

It is then created inside of a view called photos

```
App.PhotosView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    Upload.create();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your upload methods into the router.

That being said you can inject the controller into your upload object on create.

```
App.Upload = Em.Object.extend
  success: (file, response) ->
    @get('controller').set('uploadedPhotos', response)

App.PhotosView = Em.View.extend
  didInsertElement:
    controller = @get('controller')
    App.Upload.create(controller: controller)
```

Sorry about answering with coffeescript it is just faster to type.

Comment: Ok so you're injecting the controller into the object from the router and then setting it from there. 

When I replicated this approach the `App.Upload.get('controller').set('uploadedPhotos', response)` returned an error `Uncaught TypeError: (long function) has no method get`. I've seen this error quite a bit. Any idea what causes it? Shouldn't the Object prototype contain a get method?

Comment: App.Upload is a "class" not an instance. App.Upload.create() returns an instance that you can call methods on.

Comment: Ok so if it returns an instance that I can call methods on wouldn't I need to create a new instance within thin view or router?

Comment: Yes, preferably in the router.

Comment: Yeah, I wish I could articulate what sort of problems I'm having. I tried your method but it's simply throwing errors.

Comment: Try putting together a jsbin example. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/  Also do you have the Ember inspector installed in your browser, It will help you understand the objects and what properties are automatically injected.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `Upload` object just handles loading of photos. In that case, is there some reason for not having the functionality right on the `PhotosController` (making ajax call on init for example)?

Anyway, if you really need to wire controllers (I guess that Upload would need to extend `Em.Controller` instead of `Em.Object`) check this:

[Dependecies Between Controllers](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/).

Comment: Yeah the photos controller handles the uploading of the photos then we move to a new page which handles editing the uploaded photos details.